# How to combine a QLineEdit with a QPushButton having no space in between?

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qpushbutton, qlayout

I need to make an element like this:

[image]

It's a combination of a line edit and a button with the **same height** and **no space between them**.

I have tried in Qt Designer but the height of them is not the same and there is always a small space between these 2 elements.

[image]
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: layoutspacing to zero!

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ: thank you, it does not help. I have set it as in the picture.

Comment: You might want to try calling [`setFrame(false)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#frame-prop) on the `QLineEdit`.  Just a guess though.

Comment: @G.M.: thank you, with `setFrame` i do not see the border anymore. I want to see the border. When I set style sheet for the line edit after that, the line edit becomes narrower, actually, it looks even worse than now.

Comment: the problem is in used style. Actual size of lineEdit or pushButton is a little bigger, and visually there is a gap between them. You can write your own stylesheet for lineEdit or pushButton (or both) to change that behaviour, so styles for controls will be dropped and their actual bounding rect will be in your domain. You can make visual style as close as you want, but it's not crossplatform solution. OR to place the button over the lineEdit, which leads to manual contol of their respective positions without layouts (don't recommend that). OR you can rewrite used QStyle and correct spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could customize a `QComboBox`, something like this:

```
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QLineEdit>
class CustomBox : public QComboBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomBox(QWidget * parent = nullptr) : QComboBox(parent)
    {
        setEditable(true);
        QString ss =
                "QComboBox::drop-down {border: none;}"
                "QComboBox::down-arrow { image: url(/data/whatever.png); }"
                "QComboBox::down-arrow:pressed { image: url(/data/whatever-pressed.png); }";
        setStyleSheet(ss);
        connect(lineEdit(), &QLineEdit::editingFinished, [this](){
            QString t = lineEdit()->text();
            clear();
            lineEdit()->setText(t);
        });
    }
    void setText(const QString & t) { lineEdit()->setText(t); }
    QString text() const { return lineEdit()->text(); }

protected:
    void showPopup() override
    {
        emit buttonClicked();
    }
signals:
    void buttonClicked();
};
```

The combo box is set as editable, so you can use an underlying `QLineEdit`, which is, more or less, under full control through the protected `lineEdit` member function. As you can see, I connected its `editingFinished` signal to a lambda to avoid adding items to the combo each time (this happens when the user press Enter in an editable combo box).

The styling is quite simple, given that you have a couple of icons for the button.

I exposed the line edit `text` getter/setter, and added a signal for the button click, which gets emitted from the `showPopup` protected method (called when the user press the button).

Just an idea.